# Efficiency of unboxed arrays as compared to boxed arrays

Tags: haskell, dll

I have implemented an algorithm in `R`, in `Rcpp` (a `C++` library which allows to easily generate DLLs callable from `R`), and in Haskell (available [here](https://github.com/stla/hypergeomPFQ)). I have two different implementations in Haskell: one which uses boxed arrays and the other one uses unboxed arrays (both mutable arrays).

Here is the expression evaluated by the algorithm:

[image]

Useless to explain this expression, this is just to show that this is a series truncated up to an integer `m`.

I have made a DLL from the Haskell implementation which is callable from `R` (with the help of the `inline-r` library). So I can compare the speed of the four implementations in `R`. For small values of `m`, the winner is `C++`. But when I increase `m`, Haskell beats `C++`. Here is an example of benchmarks for an example with `m = 40`:

```
> benchmarks <- function(m){
+   microbenchmark(
+     R = R(m), # R evaluation
+     Rcpp = Rcpp(m), # Rcpp (C++) evaluation
+     Haskell = Haskell(m), # Haskell evaluation
+     Haskell2 = Haskell2(m), # Haskell evaluation with unboxed arrays
+     times = 2
+   )
+ }
> benchmarks(40L)
Unit: seconds
     expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval  cld
        R 100.923679 100.923679 100.948899 100.948899 100.974118 100.974118     2    d
     Rcpp  27.207624  27.207624  27.252485  27.252485  27.297347  27.297347     2   c 
  Haskell   6.981935   6.981935   7.147086   7.147086   7.312237   7.312237     2 a   
 Haskell2   8.447389   8.447389   8.629766   8.629766   8.812144   8.812144     2  b
```

One says that unboxed arrays are more efficient than boxed arrays. However this is not the case here, as you can see.

What is the reason for that ? Is there a GHC option to turn on in order to benefit from the efficiency of the unboxed arrays ? I'm making my DLLs with the default settings of `foreign-library` in the `cabal` file:

```
foreign-library Hypergeom
  buildable:           True
  type:                native-shared
  if os(Windows)
    options: standalone
  other-modules:       HyperGeomR
  build-depends:       base >=4.7 && < 5
                     , hypergeomPFQ
                     , inline-r
  hs-source-dirs:      src-dll
  c-sources:           StartEnd.c
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Comment: Haskell frequently uses list *fusion*, where in short it never constructs a list, but turns it in a looping mechanism, so avoiding the construction of `cons`, etc., Depending on the exact algorithm, it might happen that you never make a list at all, and thus that boxing/unboxing is not even relevant.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The algorithm starts with an array filled with zeros, and then the cells are filled one by one, using recursion. You can see the algorithm [here, page 840](http://math.mit.edu/~edelman/homepage/papers/hypers.pdf).

Comment: Sorry to ask a triviality, but: are the different implementations actually producing the same results (modulo rounding errors)?

Comment: @chi Yes, perfectly the same. I have also a Julia implementation and it gives the same results as well :)

Comment: Are you doing lots of concatenation of vectors?  Concating boxed vectors is a matter of allocating an array of pointers and copying the old pointers.  Concatenation of unboxed vectors involves copying the elements themselves, which is often an equal cost but can be more expensive if they are big.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson No. I'm declaring a mutable array filled with zeros and I fill each cell with `writeArray`.